# TestServer PostAsJsonAsync returns 404

Tags: asp.net, api, testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

So i'm trying to do an integration test to test a fileupload. I'm using this documentation as reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I have this method :
[image]

the PostResponse1 and PostResponse2 gives me a 404 yet the getResponse givves me a 200 with valid data.

I'm trying to get an access token for further use.
Here is the method body for the Authenticate method :

```
 [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TokenAuthController : TenantApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel pModel)
    {
        AbpLoginResult<Tenant, User> loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            pModel.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
            pModel.Password,
            GetTenancyNameOrNull()
        );

        string accessToken = CreateAccessToken(CreateJwtClaims(loginResult.Identity));

        return new AuthenticateResultModel
        {
            AccessToken = accessToken,
            EncryptedAccessToken = GetEncrpyedAccessToken(accessToken),
            ExpireInSeconds = (int)this._configuration.Expiration.TotalSeconds,
            UserId = loginResult.User.Id
        };
    }
```

why is it that the getAsync gives me a 200 yet the PostAsJsonAsync gives me a 404 ?